# Materialized views in DasbDB

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

Does 'DashDB for Transactions' support Materialized Views?

DB2 has the concept of MQT (materialized query table), but not sure if DashDb for Transactions supports the same thing, since both use the same core DB2 engine.

Comment: And, did you try it out?

Answer (score 0):

IBM dashDB does have the concept of MQT (materialized query tables) same as DB2. For an IBM source showing that check [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.apdv.porting.doc/doc/c0053114.html).

The below CREATE TABLE statement defines a materialized query table.

MQTs can significantly improve the performance of queries, especially complex queries involving aggregation, joins, repeated calculations, resource-intensive scans, and data across multiple database partitions.

MQTs are based upon the results of a query, and they store the query results as data that you can retrieve instead of the underlying tables.

To use the example statement below, edit the {} variables and choose an option in [].

```
CREATE TABLE { table-name } AS (
       SELECT { column-name }, ..., { column-name }
       FROM { table-name }, ..., { table-name } 
       -- {WHERE expression} 
       ) DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED REFRESH DEFERRED
       MAINTAINED BY USER
       ORGANIZE BY COLUMN
       ;
SET INTEGRITY FOR { table-name }
       ALL IMMEDIATE UNCHECKED
       ;
```